# OpenGL, GLSL Access violation

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to implement the OpenGL Shading language into a project using some example code. The program is now crashing when it gets to this line:

```
glShaderSourceARB(v, 1, &vv,NULL);
```

The error I am getting says their is an access violation reading location 0x00000000. When debugging I have found the values for ff, fs, vs and vv all have values of 0x00000000  according to visual C++.

Variable names are from the example code, I have the example working I just wanted to try it within one of my projects.

Below is the method to set up the shader, up until the point where the program crashes.

```
void setShaders() {

    GLint status = 0;
    char *vs = NULL,*fs = NULL;

    // Create empty shader objects:
    v = glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB);
    f = glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB);

    // read the shader code from text files:
    vs = textFileRead("toon.vert");
    fs = textFileRead("toon.frag");

    const char * ff = fs;
    const char * vv = vs;

    //Set the shader source

    glShaderSourceARB(v, 1, &vv,NULL);

    glShaderSourceARB(f, 1, &ff,NULL);

    . . . .
}
```

Comment: Well... does textFileRead() return NULL? I bet it does. Like when it cannot find the specified file.

Comment: Glaringly obvious now, buy yes it was an incorrect path to the file, Thanks!